# PHP Выполнять скрипт на фоне

Tags: php

Интересует вопрос как можно реализовать задуманное:
Пользователь нажимает кнопку "Сбор данных", на фоне запускается мой скрипт, он делает свою работу, все записывает в бд, при этом пользователь может спокойно дальше гулять по сайту, а на странице где был запущен скрипт должна появится надпись "Собираем данные" например.

Буду рад любым статьям или примерам!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Если у вас fast-cgi + php-fpm на сервере, то можно использовать функцию `fastcgi_finish_request();` она отдает ответ браузеру, при этом скрипт продолжает выполняться на сервере, периодически записывая куда-то состояние выполнения задачи

Вариант 2. Серверы очередей (например rabbitMQ). Ваш web-скрипт бросает задачу в очередь. Отдельно запущенный на сервере скрипт мониторит очередь и выполняет появившуюся задачу, периодически записывая куда-то состояние выполнения задачи

Вариант 3. На сервере, на локалхосте и неиспользуемом порту запускаете еще один веб-сервер, с большими параметрами таймаута на выполнение скриптов. Ваш скрипт просто бросает задачу на 127.0.0.1:8888 и рапортует о постановке задачи. На локальном же сервере происходит выполнение, периодически записывая куда-то состояние выполнения задачи

Вариант 4. Добавляете задачу в некий список. По крону запускается скрипт, который выполняет их по списку, периодически записывая куда-то состояние выполнения задачи

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее очевидное решение - ставится задача, PHP закидывает её в RabbitMQ. Из RabbitMQ её подхватывает подписанный на очередь демон, после чего выполняет и выставляет флаг, что задача выполнена. Можно в Redis по ID задачи или какому-то другому идентификатору, а можно прямо в базе.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

Делается так:

- Создаете табличку "Задачи", например
- Пользователь нажимает кнопку "Сбор данных" - задача добавляется в таблицу "Задачи"
- Скриптом берем задачу из таблицы, метим ее как "Выполняется". Соответственно пользователю выводится надпись "Собираем данные"
- После выполнения, метим ее как выполненную или не выполненную
- Сооответственное пользователю выводит результат выполнения задачи

Ну и выполнять это все можно с помощью `cron`

Comment: cron будет запускаться не чаще чем раз в минуту. То есть в среднем задача будет выполнятся з задержкой 30 секунд.

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Ваш вариант решения?

Comment: php-воркер под supervisord + очередь

Comment: :) Думаю в его случае крона будет достаточно